# Get the size of a viewport in a QScrollArea in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

We are writing a program to display a video from a microscope. The size of the video is 2208 * 1648. This is much bigger than the available screensize. So I use a QScrollArea to show it.

```
    self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
    self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
    self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.imageLabel)
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
```

This scales the video to the size of the viewport. So initialy the video is shown completely in the viewport of the scrollarea without scrollbars. Now it must be possible to zoom in on a particular part of the video. So a zoomfactor can be entered. When this is done the following code is executed:

```
def scaleImage(self, factor):
    self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
    self.imageLabel.resize(factor * self.imageLabel.pixmap().size())

    self.adjustScrollBar(self.scrollArea.horizontalScrollBar(), factor)
    self.adjustScrollBar(self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar(), factor)
```

When the actual video is shown, the images are sent to the label using the following function

```
def set_image(self, pixmap):
    self.imageLabel.set_image(pixmap, self.current_width, self.current_height)
    self.imageLabel.resize(self.current_zoomfactor * self.imageLabel.pixmap().size())
```

This works. However there are several problems:
1. setWidgetResizable does not honor the aspectratio
2. When a user zooms out, eventually the picture becomes smaller than the viewport, which is not what I want.
3. I tried to get the size of the viewport using

```
sizehint = self.scrollArea.viewportSizeHint()
```

Then I do get a size which looks more or less correct, however when I resize the window the result does not change.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: I'll answer this myself....

Comment: It proves that the size is adjusted correctly, but I was confused by initial values that were not correct because the widget had not been built completely.

Answer (score 1):

Before the resize the zoom factor is calculated:

```
def handle_min_zoomfactor(self, new_zoomfactor):
    self.minimal_zoom  = self.scrollArea.viewport().width() / self.sensor_width
    if new_zoomfactor < self.minimal_zoom:
        new_zoomfactor = self.minimal_zoom
    if new_zoomfactor > 1.0:
        new_zoomfactor = 1
```

After that scaleImage is called.

Comment: Hi Dick, this is an old thread but I'm working on something similar--a GUI for microscope image segmentation software. Is this code available anywhere? I'm, new to PyQt and I've had a lot of trouble getting all the moving parts working together